# List all files in folders and subfolders using Dropbox API and python

Tags: python-3.x, dropbox-api

I have the task of reorganizing our company's Dropbox.  I am using Python and the Dropbox API and my goal is to pull a list of all the files in the folders and subfolders of our Team Dropbox.

So far, my code looks is from their basic code and **I would like just a little help in understanding how to list the files in each of the subfolders as well**.

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('API')
dbx.users_get_current_account()

for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('/Company Team Folder').entries:
    print(entry.name)
```

Thank you for any guidance on this.

Comment: I recommend reading the Dropbox [File Access Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/lp/developers/reference/dbx-file-access-guide) and [Team Files Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/lp/developers/reference/dbx-team-files-guide) for information on how to work with the Dropbox filesystem via the Dropbox API.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Greg.  I have been reading and experimenting a bit.  So when adding the `include_media_info=True` flag (for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('/HEC-TV Team Folder', include_media_info=True).entries), I don't seem to get any extra metadata.  I am able to see the filename but that's it.  I appreciate any guidance.  Thank you.

Comment: Please post a new question with the details and unexpected output.

Answer (score 2):

For someone who got here in search of the answer, here is the solution to list all files in folders and subfolders using Dropbox API and python

```
def i_am_dropbox(token):
    my_client = Dropbox(token)
    file_list = my_client.files_list_folder('', recursive=True)
    
    # WE DID NOT CHECK HASMORE!
    folder_list = [x.name for x in file_list.entries if 'size' not in dir(x)]
    
    # List of both folders and files...
    list_of_files = [x.name for x in file_list.entries]
    
    # print folder_list
    return folder_list, list_of_files
```

See more sample code at: https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/dropbox/Dropbox/files_list_folder/python-dropbox-files_list_folder-method-examples.html